# Pass scope to directive ($uibModal.open method)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I'd like to create custom directive to show some data based on parent's (controller) scope.

Directive JS code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('blabla')
        .directive('showActiveTask', showActiveTask);

    showActiveTask.$inject = ['$uibModal'];

    function showActiveTask($uibModal) {

        return {
            //replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                taskData: '='
            },
            template: '<button type="submit"' +
            '        class="btn grey lighten-1 btn-raised white-text btn-sm"' +
            '        ng-click="open()">' +
            '    <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">View assigned tasks</span>' +
            '</button>',
            link: linkFunc
        };

        function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.showLabel = false;
            console.log(scope);

            scope.open = function () {
                vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'blabla.html',
                    size: 'lg',
                    controller: scope.taskData,
                    backdrop: true,
                    resolve: {
                        console.log('babla')
                        }
                    }
                }).result.then(function () {
                    console.log("wanna switch");
                });
                console.log(scope)
            };

            scope.clear = function () {
                console.log('close modal');
                vm.modalInstance.close();
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

Controller JS code:

When I click to show this directive I receive message: "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object" - it's obvious, beacuse I'm trying to pass scope object as controller, but here: http://brilliantbritz.com/2014/08/09/create-a-dynamic-modal-directive-in-minutes-using-angular-and-ui-bootstrap/ is the same. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn it. It was obvious: to create modal based on parent's controller scope just pass its scope as parameter:

```
    scope.open = function () {
        vm.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'blabla.html',
            size: 'lg',
            scope: scope,
            backdrop: true,
            resolve: {
                text: function () {
                    return '<strong><p>Are you sure you want to close?</p></strong>'
                }
            }
        }).result.then(function () {
            console.log("wanna switch");
        });


    };
```